# Modifying existing Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex that validates the allowed characters:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-?\/:;(){}\[\]|`~´.\,'+÷ !@#$£%^"&*_<>=àáâäçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüýßÀÁÂÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜÑ\\]*$
```

I need to modify it so that the string being validated:

1. may not begin with space or “/”
2. may not contain “//”
3. may not end with “/”

For the space at the beginning I have adapted it to

```
^[^\s][a-zA-Z0-9-?\\/:;(){}\\[\\]|`~´.\\,'+÷ !@#$£%^\"&*_<>=àáâäçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüýßÀÁÂÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜÑ\\\\]*$
```

Not sure what to do about the other two requirements
For the second one I tried combining it with ^((?!//))*$ in various ways but to no success.

Comment: @Biffen No it does not. Or do you think all answers on SO should just point to general documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `^((?!\/\/))*$` matches any empty string since the lookahead is a non-consuming pattern and here it always returns *true*.

`[^\s]` at the start of your pattern will match any chars other than whitespace chars, even those you did not specify in the character class.

You can use

```java
^(?![\s/])(?!.*//)[a-zA-Z0-9?/:;(){}\[\]|`~´.,'+÷ !@#$£%^\"&*_<>=àáâäçèéêëìíîïñòóôöùúûüýßÀÁÂÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÖÙÚÛÜÑ\\-]*$(?<!/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Vm5LC/1). *Details*:

- `^(?![\s/])(?!.*//)` - at the start of string, two checks are peformed:

  - `(?![\s/])` - no whitespace or `/` allowed (right at the start)
  - `(?!.*//)` - no `//` allowed anywhere after zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?<!/)` is the check after the end of string is hit, and it fails the match if the last char in string is `/`.

Note that in Java regex declarations, you do not need to escape `/` since regex delimiter notation is not used, and `/` itself is not a special regex metacharacter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the following regexp should be enough and more simple: `(?!.*//)^[^ /].*[^/]$`

So at the beginning you can use negative lookahead to prevent occurence of `//` anywhere in the text. Then any character but space and `/` is accepted at the beginning, then anything can be present (besides `//` which was excluded by negative lookahead) and anything but `/` is accepted at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Since 95% of the time the special conditions on the space and forward slash
will not occur, it might be better to take those two characters out of your
big class and handle them separately if and when they occur.

The big class can also be condensed to speed things up a bit.

```
^(?>[a-zA-Z0-9\\!-.:-@\[\]-`{-~£´ÄÖäö÷À-ÂÇ-ÏÑ-ÔÙ-Üß-âç-ïñ-ôù-ý]+|(?:/(?!/|$)|[ ])(?<!^.))*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/LpCwt6/1

```
 ^ 
 (?>
    [a-zA-Z0-9\\!-.:-@\[\]-`{-~£´ÄÖäö÷À-ÂÇ-ÏÑ-ÔÙ-Üß-âç-ïñ-ôù-ý]+ 
  | (?:
       /
       (?! / | $ )
     | [ ] 
    )
    (?<! ^ . )
 )*
 $
```

And if you want to absorb all the class characters it can get very small.

```
^(?>[!-.0-~£´ÄÖäö÷À-ÂÇ-ÏÑ-ÔÙ-Üß-âç-ïñ-ôù-ý]+|(?:/(?!/|$)|[ ])(?<!^.))*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/EYdM5C/1